# Raspberry Pi file not found when present in location

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi

I am following [this tutorial](https://www.learnopencv.com/install-opencv-4-on-raspberry-pi/) to Installing OpenCv on my Raspberry Pi.

However, when I get to the stage to install the virtual environment the following commands execute without issue:

```
cd $cwd
python3 -m venv OpenCV-"$cvVersion"-py3
echo "# Virtual Environment Wrapper" >> ~/.bashrc
echo "alias workoncv-$cvVersion=\"source $cwd/OpenCV-$cvVersion-py3/bin/activate\"" >> ~/.bashrc
```

However, the last command on that list `source "$cwd"/OpenCV-"$cvVersion"-py3/bin/activate` throws an error `bash: /OpenCV-master-py3/bin/activate: No such file or directory`

I've tried using `sudo` before the command along with repeating the entire process with `sudo-s`. When I check the file path the full file is located there with instructions at the top

> `#`This file must be used with "source bin/activate" *from bash*
>
> `#`you cannot run it directly

I've tried skipping that step and moving onto the next one but then I get another error: `sed: can't read /etc/dphy: No such file or directory` - but that's a whole different question.

How can I get the terminal to find the file that I can?

Comment: Is looks like `$cvVersion` env var isn't set looking at the error message `/OpenCV--py3`. I think you need to run `cvVersion="master"` first to set the variable looking at the tutorial. Also, it looks like the tutorial has a typo `cvVersion="masrer"` where i think it should be `master`.

Comment: @HarryCho I've given it a go and I get the same message except it now says `/OpenCV-master-py3/bin/activate: No such file or directory` I'll have a look back through the tutorial and see if any other steps need changing.

Comment: Looks like $cwd isn't populated since it claims the path starts at / directly.  try using $PWD instead. `echo "alias workoncv-$cvVersion=\"source $PWD/OpenCV-$cvVersion-py3/bin/activate\"" >> ~/.bashrc `

Comment: @estabroo that worked, thank's for your help, now I've just got to find /etc/dphy now :)